# If a mapping on complete metric space is continuous, then mapping on space of closed and bounded sets of that metric space is also continuous ??

Tags: functional-analysis

If a mapping on complete metric space $X$ is continuous, then mapping defined for sets, on space of closed and bounded sets of $X$ is also continuous ??

Comment: No it's not continuous in general. To get more information, please improve your question by adding the relevant definitions and your thoughts on this problem.

Comment: why would X have to be complete metric? and do you mean 'subsets of X'?

Comment: here is my detailed question. If F  is a closed set- valued map from X  to Y and A is a subset of X, and X is complete metric space then the image of the set A under F is given by F(A) = {y: y belongs to F(x): x in A}, let CB(X) denote space of closed and bounded sets. If F is continuous on set- valued map, then F is continuous on CB(X), is that true??

Comment: plzz help me in this

Comment: If F is a closed set- valued map from X to Y and A⊂X, then the image of the set A under F is given by $F(A) = \lbrace y: y \in F(x): x \in A \rbrace $, let $CB(X)$ denote space of closed and bounded sets. Is it true that if F is continuous on set- valued map, then F is continuous on $CB(X)$?

Comment: You should [edit] your question instead of adding comments.